# Postfix blacklist not working

Tags: centos, email, postfix

I am trying to blacklist some email addresses but I simply can't get postfix access to work.

Can some point out what I might have don't incorrectly?

Added

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_senders
```

to the main.cf file in /etc/postfix/

Created /etc/postfix/check_senders
I added my address to the file to check that it's functioning
This file contains

```
myemail@domain.com REJECT
```

Created postfix lookup tables with

```
#>postmap /etc/postfix/check_senders
```

Reload and restart postfix

```
#>postfix reload
#>postfix restart
```

To test this I created very basic php mail script called test.php

```
<?php
$to = 'myemail@domain.com';
$subject = 'Test postfix access';
$headers = "From: My Name <" . strip_tags('myemail@domain.com') . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($to) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
if (mail($to, $subject, 'Test is a test message from the server', $headers)) echo "Sent\n\r";
```

Ran the file with

```
#>php test.php
```

I still receive the email sent by the php script ..... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you might have two issues here:

1. `check_sender_access` checks the [**envelope** sender address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_address). In your php script you only set the "From:"-Header. The envelope sender is probably something completely different (see the "Return-Path" header in the resulting message)
2. if you run this php script on the same server as postfix, `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` will not trigger. the php mail()-function submits a mail with the sendmail binary by default, so smtpd is not involved.

-> the problem might not be your postfix config, but your test with php. Try sending an email from an external mail source (like a gmail account ) and see if your blacklist works then

Comment: I see what you mean. The above s my attempt to achieve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160884/postfix-conditional-rules-base-on-sending-address